# How to get embedding vector from an image using Deepface?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, resnet, keras-vggface

I have a ***face recognition*** project using features extraction.

***I want to generate the embedding vector using DeepFace or VGGFace instead of ResNet-34 without changing the whole scripts. Any help will be appreciated***

I've written a script **(encoding.py)** doing **features extraction** based on **ResNet-34**. The script loops throw images in the train-set and extract the encoding **(a 128-d vector)** and the name of each image from the train set, then put them in a dictionary.

And when executing this script we generate a file **(encodings.pickle)** that contains our dictionary.

*The script is below:*

```
from imutils import paths
import face_recognition
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input directory of faces + images")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
    help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="cnn",
    help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# grab the paths to the input images in our dataset
print("[INFO] quantifying faces...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))
# initialize the list of known encodings and known names
knownEncodings = []
knownNames = []

# loop over the image paths
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    # extract the person name from the image path
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1,
        len(imagePaths)))
    name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    # load the input image and convert it from BGR (OpenCV ordering)
    # to dlib ordering (RGB)
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes
    # corresponding to each face in the input image
    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
        model=args["detection_method"])
    # compute the facial embedding for the face
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
    # loop over the encodings
    for encoding in encodings:
        # add each encoding + name to our set of known names and
        # encodings
        knownEncodings.append(encoding)
        knownNames.append(name)

# dump the facial encodings + names to disk
print("[INFO] serializing encodings...")
data = {"encodings": knownEncodings, "names": knownNames}
f = open(args["encodings"], "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(data))
f.close()
```

And to make predictions I've used another script that loads a single image then do the encoding part and make a comparison between its encoding and the file generated before.

*The 2nd script is below:*

```
# import the necessary packages
import face_recognition
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
    help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="hog",
    help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


# load the known faces and embeddings
print("[INFO] loading encodings...")
data = pickle.loads(open(args["encodings"], "rb").read())


# load the input image and convert it from BGR to RGB
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes corresponding
# to each face in the input image, then compute the facial embeddings
# for each face
print("[INFO] recognizing faces...")
boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
    model=args["detection_method"])
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
# initialize the list of names for each face detected
names = []

# loop over the facial embeddings
for encoding in encodings:
    # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
    # encodings
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
        encoding)
    name = "Unknown"

    # check to see if we have found a match
    if True in matches:
        # find the indexes of all matched faces then initialize a
        # dictionary to count the total number of times each face
        # was matched
        matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
        counts = {}
        # loop over the matched indexes and maintain a count for
        # each recognized face face
        for i in matchedIdxs:
            name = data["names"][i]
            counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1
        # determine the recognized face with the largest number of
        # votes (note: in the event of an unlikely tie Python will
        # select first entry in the dictionary)
        name = max(counts, key=counts.get)
    
    # update the list of names
    names.append(name)
print(names)
# loop over the recognized faces
for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
    # draw the predicted face name on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
    cv2.putText(image, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.75, (0, 255, 0), 2)
# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

DeepFace has a represent function in its interface.

```
from deepface import DeepFace
img_path = "img.jpg"
models = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "Dlib", "ArcFace"]
embedding = DeepFace.represent(img_path, model_name = models[0])
```

If you already read an image, you can pass it directly to the deepface instead of passing its exact path.

```
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
embedding = DeepFace.represent(image, model_name = models[0])
```